# Disable and Enable dropdown in IE6 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, html-select

I am using

```
selectElement.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to disable a dropdown in IE6, and using

```
selectElement.removeAttr('disabled');
```

to re-enable it.  But it remains disabled and greyed out. Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: My question is: what is your target audience that you even care how/if it works in IE6? Only [about 6% of the world still uses IE6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/), with more than half of that being China, so unless you are building a Chinese site, don't worry about it.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First thing to check: Your jQuery version.
  I found [this reference](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-remove-attribute-disabled-from-select-ie6) to a jQuery bug in IE6 with `removeAttr` on `select` elements. This bug is in 1.6.2, and is marked as fixed. Make sure you're on the latest version of jQuery, currently 1.7.2.
- Second thing to check: Your HTML.
  I found [this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-remove-attribute-disabled-from-select-ie6), where it seems that IE6 requires the element to have the same `id` and `name` attributes for this to work.
- Third suggestion:
  Try using jQuery's `.prop()` and `.removeProp()` methods instead of the `attr` methods. (manual page: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/)

Finally, I will echo what has probably been said to you many times already: please stop supporting IE6. The sooner we can all forget about this browser the better.

It's worth pointing out that jQuery are planning to drop support for IE6, IE7 and IE8 (yes, all three of them) in v2.0, due out some time in the middle of next year. You'll still be able to use older versions of jQuery, of course, but it does make the point about how far behind you are if you're still on IE6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a well documented problem with IE6/IE7.

A quick Google search revealed this potential workaround: http://www.goodercode.com/wp/disable-select-options-internet-explorer-jquery/

Comment: I meant disabling the entire select element, not individual options though.